# How to Show specific image on popup when a label is clicked using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have following two labels on my web from.

```
           <div class="StatsItem" style="border-bottom: 0px;">
            <div class="lFloat iStore MarginTop4" ></div>

                   <asp:Label  runat="server" ID="lblStore" Text="N/A"         CssClass="changeColor spnValue"    ></asp:Label>
        </div>
        <div class="StatsItem" style="border-bottom: 0px;">
            <div class="lFloat iReview MarginTop4"></div>
                <asp:Label  runat="server" ID="lblReview" Text="N/A" CssClass="changeColor spnValue" ></asp:Label>
        </div>
```

and popup with following two divs

```
            <div class="lFloat iStore MarginTop10" id="dvstoreicon"></div>
            <div class="lFloat iReview MarginTop10" id="dvreviewicon"></div>
```

I want to show icon related to button clicked. I am confused how i get the id of icons before that popup is not shown up?or how I pass clicked event to be handle on popup.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following Demo:

```
<div class="StatsItem" style="border-bottom: 0px;" onclick="return OpenPopup('Show store icon');">
    <div class="lFloat iStore MarginTop4"  ></div>
               <asp:Label  runat="server" ID="lblStore" Text="Store" CssClass="changeColor spnValue"    ></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <div class="StatsItem" style="border-bottom: 0px;" onclick="return OpenPopup('Show Review icon');">
        <div class="lFloat iReview MarginTop4" ></div>
        <asp:Label  runat="server" ID="lblReview" Text="Review" CssClass="changeColor spnValue" ></asp:Label>
    </div>

     <div class="lFloat iStore MarginTop10" id="dvstoreicon"></div>
        <div class="lFloat iReview MarginTop10" id="dvreviewicon"></div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    function OpenPopup(value) {
        alert(value);
    }
</script>
```

Here i am showing alert instead of popup. Please modify code as per requirement. In alert you can see label name on click.

Hope it will help you. Please let me know if you need more clarification.